# Multiple if and for loop in list comprehension

Tags: python

I am facing issue while converting my below code in list comprehension

```
A = {
  "name": ['sahil', 'pankaj', 'honey'],
  'test': 'data'
}

Mylist = []
for k, v in A.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i in v:
            Mylist.append(i)
    else:
        Mylist.append(v)
```

I tried this code via list comprehension but failed to get the result

```
Mylist = [i
  for k, v in A.items() if isinstance(v, list) for i in v
  else i = v
]
```

I am facing issue syntax error.

Comment: Can you share that syntax error you are talking about? Additionally, please explain what you've tried to solve that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you know that key `'name'` holds a list and the key `'test'` holds a string you can use:

```
Mylist = [e for e in [*A['name'], A['test']]]
```

and more simple:

```
Mylist = [*A['name'], A['test']]
```

in the above line, you are creating a list using the unpacking operator and your string element

**output:**

```
['sahil', 'pankaj', 'honey', 'data']
```

or if you do not want wnat to use the dict keys you can use:

```
Mylist = [i for e in A.values()  for i in (e if isinstance(e, list) else [e])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `keys()` method of the `dict` structure to get the values into a list. Hope this helps too

```
  A = {
    "name": ['sahil', 'pankaj', 'honey'],
    "test": 'data'
  }

 Mylist = []
 for k in A.keys():
    if k == "name":
       Mylist.extend(A[k]) #using extend as we already have a list present in the value for the dict, this just concatenates into one main list
    else:
       Mylist.append(A[k])
 print(Mylist)
```

OR just using a list comprehension:

```
   A = {
    "name": ['sahil', 'pankaj', 'honey'],
    "test": 'data'
   }
   Mylist = [v for (k,v) in A.items() if k == "name"] #only returns values for k equal to "name"

   print(Mylist)
```

Comment: list comprehension would be more efficient

Comment: i want value of data as well

Comment: my output is look like ['sahil','pankaj','honey','data']

Comment: just update `k != None` and that should return data in the list as well